# What is a pin header with a wall on one side called?

Tags: identification, connector

What do we call a Pin header that has wall of one side to ensure you don't connect it wrong(Male side) and on female side there is a slot opening for the wall so it sits and fits perfectly?
Sorry I don't have a picture, I have just seen it but don't know what the name is hence can't find to buy.
[image: The picture]

The one in this pic for SPI and RS232.

Comment: There are many types of these.

Comment: ok! I'll try to find a picture on google

Comment: You are looking for KEYED headers.

Comment: A latching pin header.

Comment: There are shrouds , retainers and clips for headers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A latching pin header is what I think you refer to: -

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Curiously enough, Digikey, at least, categorizes this type of header as an "unshrouded header":

[image]

But within this category, they distinguish the feature you're asking about as "shrouded - 1 wall":

[image]

I happen to have been searching for a similar connector yesterday, and if your part has 0.1" pin spacing you will likely find a match in either the Molex KK series or TE MTA-100 series.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to other answers,

Be careful here, latching connectors  by themselves do not guarantee connector alignment if the corresponding female part does not include a mating feature.

Fully shrouded connectors or keyed connectors do.

Another trick to ensure correct alignment that is commonly used is to remove one pin from the header and plug the associated pin on the female part. The female part usually has a hole-plug/polarizing key accessory you can purchase.

[image]
[image]

That can, in some cases, work out cheaper than fully keyed connectors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, such connectors don't have an industry-standard name.

I dire need for a name for them (for a book), I named them ["Single-wall connectors"](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=single_wall_conn) and I invite you all to call them that as well.